# Al ejecutar la función, solo aparece el mensaje de finalización, no el de proceso

Tags: javascript

No logro que se despliegue el mensaje "Procesando" en el siguiente código. Cuando lo ejecuto solo me aparece el mensaje de "Finalizado" pero no aparece el mensaje "Procesando".

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function calc() {
            procesando();
            document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = "Procesando";
            var dummy = 0;
            for (var i=0; i<1000000000;i++) {
                for (var z=0; i<1000000000;i++) {
                    dummy = dummy + z + i;
                }
            }
            finalizado();
        }

        function procesando() {
            document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = "Procesando";
        }

        function finalizado() {
            document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = "Finalizado";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="calc();">Calcular</button>
    <p id="mensaje"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Para que sirve ese doble for? Supongo que tu intención primero es mostrar el procesando una cierta cantidad de tiempo y después el finalizado?

Comment: si que lo muestra, solo que con los bucles for queda el navegador como colgado hasta que termina. si antes de la linea que pone `var dummy = 0` pones `debugger` al pararse el renderizado, puedes ver que pone procesando en la página

Comment: Buenas tardes, gracias por responder, el código es solo un ejemplo, el proceso que deseo realizar es una consulta extensa a una base de datos que se demora, y no logo que aparezca un mensaje que diga "Procesando"

Comment: para eso usa setTimeout, que ejecuta una funcion al cabo del tiempo que deseas. Ej `setTimeout(()=> console.log("hola"), 5000)` mostrará por consola hola al cabo de 5 segundos

Comment: Es que no le serviría, porque si está esperando un mensaje que depende de la consulta a una base de datos, entonces sería una petición asíncrona. No puede establecer un tiempo determinado para algo que no sabe cuando volverá. En todo caso trabaja con promesas.

Comment: Gracias por responder Suso, Triby acaba de publicar el código corregido agregando el setTimeout que recomiendas, lo probaré, espero que funciones, Gracias de nuevo

Comment: No pasa nada, pero en vista de tu comentario de la respuesta de Triby si que era lo que querías, lo que pasa es que querías que te lo diera todo mascado. Te puse un ejemplo de lo que había que hacer, tu lo que querías era todo el código

Comment: Insisto compañero @Erick, si lo que trabajas es con base de datos y esperas a que la consulta se resuelva, el setTimeOut no será la solución más eficiente. En cualquier otro caso, te puede servir perfectamente. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu sugerencia Suso, he leído mucho sobre setTimejout, callback sinc asic promise y lo he probado sin conseguir que funciones unos tres días, gracias a que me lo pasaron masticadito lo logré y no puedo creer que sea tan sencillo de conseguir.  Te agradesco también lsanchezo, la solución de Suso y Trybi funcionaron perfectamente.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript trabaja con un solo hilo de procesos, enviando cada nueva instrucción a la cola; al parecer, los ciclos se ejecutan antes de actualizaciones de elementos en el navegador.

Lo que puedes hacer es asegurar que primero se actualice el contenedor y, después, enviar los ciclos a la cola mediante [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/setTimeout).

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function calc() {
            procesando();
            setTimeout(() => {
                var dummy = 0;
                for (var i=0; i<1000000000;i++) {
                    for (var z=0; i<1000000000;i++) {
                        dummy = dummy + z + i;
                    }
                }
                finalizado();
            }, 5);
        }

        function procesando() {
            document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = "Procesando";
        }

        function finalizado() {
            document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = "Finalizado";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="calc();">Calcular</button>
    <p id="mensaje"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchísimas gracias, era justo lo que necesitaba

Comment: No hace falta ponerle 5 milisegundos al setTimeout, si le pones 0 tambien funciona. Tal como dicen en la [documentación en inglés](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout): `If this parameter is omitted, a value of 0 is used, meaning execute "immediately", or more accurately, the next event cycle.`, o sea, a mi entender pasan al siguiente ciclo de eventos en este caso.

Comment: Tienes razón, ya lo puse en 0, gracias

Comment: @Erick Si esta respuesta responde a tu pregunta, deberías aceptarla para que la comunidad lo sepa y no quede eternamente pendiente, gracias. Consulta [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) para aprender a aceptar respuestas. También, para aprender cómo funciona este sitio haz el [tour] y así obtendrás una nueva medalla!