# Otro problema con funciones

Tags: javascript, funciones

El día de ayer ya me ayudaron con un problema, pero trato de modificar el código y no logro hacer que funciones. Tengo un programa que hace proceso muy largo (para el código que publiqué solo reemplacé ese proceso largo por un for) y los usuarios se quejan que no sabe cuánto falta para que se acabe el proceso o si va por la mitad o por el final. Lo que necesito es que le aparezca al usuario un mensaje indicando el mes y el año que va realizando el proceso para que sepa que el programa no se colgó y que sepa por qué mes y qué año va el proceso, pero solo me aparece el mensaje de "Finalizado".

Espero que me ayuden, gracias de antemano por sus respuestas.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function calc() {
            for (var anio=2017; anio<2022;anio++) {
                for (var mes=1; mes<12;mes++) {
                    mensajeMesAnio(mes,anio);
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        procesoMesAnio(mes,anio);
                    }, 0);
                }
            }
            finalizado();
        }
        function mensajeMesAnio(mes,anio) {
            document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = "Procesando "+mes+"/"+anio;
        }
        function procesoMesAnio() {
            // proceso
            var dummy = 0;
            for (var i=0; i<100000000;i++) {
                dummy = dummy + i;
            }
        }
        function finalizado() {
            document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = "Finalizado";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="calc();">Calcular</button>
    <p id="mensaje"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: En al funcion `procesoMesAnio()`, tienes una variable, `z`, que no tienes definida en ningun lado. por otro lado, en esa funcion no procesas ni mes ni año, nose porque los pasas como variable.

Comment: @Erick: Si vas creando un nuevo nick cada vez que entras perdemos el historial de tus preguntas, las cuales nos pueden ayudar a entender a lo que te refieres cuando las mentas. Puedes fusionar/combinar cuentas de stackoverflow pidiéndolo en el [formulario de contacto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/contact).

Comment: Hola Adrigo, tienes razón, ya modifiqué el código sin la varialbe z.  Pero igual, no me aparecen los mensajes de "Procesando mes/anio" solo me aparece el mensaje de "Finalizado".

Comment: Buenos días masterguru, si, lo siento, acabo ya de registrarme, las siguiente preguntas las haré ingresando con mi correo y contraseña

Comment: Eso es porque al final del todo llamas a la función y pones que te escriba eso. Si quieres ver los menajes de la función `mensajeMesAnio()`, puedes poner lo que tienes dentro del método en un `console.log()`, en vez de `innerHTML`, ya que lo que haces es sobreescribirlo

Comment: @Erick , para que nos salga que has respondio, pon el `@` con el nombre de usuario y podremos ver que nos has respondido, voy a mirar que pasa con tu codigo tras las modificaciones

Comment: Pon en el título _cuál es el problema en cuestión_. La pregunta y sus respuestas deben ser útiles no solo para ti, sino también para otros que tengan el mismo problema más adelante. Tu pregunta no será fácil de encontrar si se titula "Otro problema con funciones". Además: ¿cuál es el resultado esperado? ¿Cuál es el obtenido? Lee [ask].

Comment: Para los que no conozcan de donde viene esta pregunta, es la segunda parte de esta otra que fue bien respondida en su momento: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/540438/problemas-con-funciones

Comment: @masterguru, eso quiere decir que esta pergunta ya esta respondida?

Comment: @adrigo No, para nada, es un nuevo caso. En la pregunta anterior la respuesta fue encerrar en un setTimeout el bucle for para poder mostrar el "procesando..." al principio, pero en este es distinto, quiere ir mostrando y variando un "procesando mes/año" mientras se ejecuta, y lo está intentando usar dentro del for, y javascript no lo interpreta como el pretende

Comment: Sería más fácil tratar de ayudar con un ejemplo real, Javascript funciona muy diferente de otros lenguajes de programación y, suponiendo que logres hacer aparecer el mensaje con ciclos, cuando trates de aplicarlo en tu proyecto no va a trabajar igual.

Comment: Aunque fuera una pregunta de seguimiento, es necesario mejorar la pregunta. Además, falta aceptar la respuesta en la [anterior pregunta](/q/540438), ya que el OP mencionó "era justo lo que necesitaba"

Comment: @Erick, mírate mi respuesta y ejecútala y verás que aparentemente funciona. Y coincido con padaleiana, debes aceptar la respuesta a la anterior pregunta para que este sitio "fluya" adecuadamente. Si no lo haces vas a perder posibles ayudas futuras pues este sitio se basa en la colaboracion de **todos**, y si tan solo vienes a sacar código como que no apetece tanto mirar tus problemas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que a mi me ha salido bien de este modo (a fuerza de prueba y error, todo hay que decirlo):

```js
function calc() {
  for (var anio = 2017; anio < 2022; anio++) {
    for (var mes = 1; mes < 12; mes++) {
      procesoMesAnio(mes, anio);
    }
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    finalizado();
  }, 0)
}

function mensajeMesAnio(mes, anio) {
  document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = "Procesando " + mes + "/" + anio;
}

function procesoMesAnio(mes, anio) {
  // proceso
  setTimeout(() => {
    mensajeMesAnio(mes, anio);
    var dummy = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
      dummy = dummy + i;
    }
  }, 0)
}

function finalizado() {
  document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = "Finalizado";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="calc();">Calcular</button>
  <p id="mensaje"></p>
</body>
```

Basándome en lo que se habia respondido en la anterior pregunta del OP: [Problemas con funciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/540438/problemas-con-funciones) he ido jugando con el setTimeout y console.log hasta conseguir el código que "teoricamente" responde a su pregunta (y no me pregunteis como, me remito a lo explicado en la respuesta aceptada de la anterior pregunta).

Comment: Muchas gracias masterguru, funcionó perfectamente

Comment: @Erick, pues acepta la respuesta.  En [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás como. Y coincido con padaleiana, debes aceptar la respuesta a la anterior pregunta para que este sitio "fluya" adecuadamente. Si no lo haces vas a perder posibles ayudas futuras pues este sitio se basa en la colaboracion de todos, y si tan solo vienes a sacar código como que no apetece tanto mirar tus problemas.  De ahí que tambien deberias fusionar perfiles, para aceptar las respuestas anteriores que te fueron útiles.

Comment: @Erick Lecturas recomendadas para aprender el funcionamiento de este sitio: [tour] , [ask] y [example]

Comment: Gracias, voy a leer esos manuales para aprender sobre cómo usar correctamente este este sitio

Comment: @Erick, perfecto, gracias por tu colaboración! :-)

Answer (score 1):

El problema por el que no te aparece nada es que estás sobreescribiendo una y otra vez los elementos, esto quiere decir que una vez escrito algo, lo sobreescribes y queda lo último que ha escrito, en este caso "finalizado". Para que te funcione, teniendo el código como lo tienes, solo tienes que cambiar las dos líneas que tienen `document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML =` y ponerles justo antes del `=` un `+`, quedando: `document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML +=`, de esta forma no sobreescribes el contenido, sino que lo concatenas.

Comment: mmm, lo acabo de intentar y nada.  La idea es que el mensaje vaya 'cambiando' así "Procesando 1/2017" luego "Procesando 2/2017" luego "Procesando 3/2017" etc y al finalizar el mensaje debe quedar en "Finalizado", pero doy click en "Calcular" y solo aparece el mensaje de "Finalizado"

Comment: @Erick eso no lo has especificado en ningun lado... se mas concreto la proxima vez... de todas formas que quieres? que salga una fecha, pase un segundo y despues la sieguinte y asi hasta que finalice? Eso que pides de ir cambiando ira demasiado rapido y no dara tiempo de verlo...

Comment: Tienes razón, no lo especifiqué claramente, lo siento.  Tengo un programa que hace proceso muy largo (para el código que publiqué solo reemplacé ese proceso largo por un for) y los usuarios se quejan que no sabe cuánto falta para que se acabe el proceso o si va por la mitad o por el final.  Lo que necesito es que le aparezca al usuario un mensaje indicando el mes y el año que va realizando el proceso para que sepa que el programa no se colgó y que sepa por qué mes y qué año va el proceso, pero solo me aparece el mensaje de "Finalizado"